# Can I use the array from nearbySearch() without putting it on a map?

Tags: google-maps

According to the documentation of the [Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests) provided by Google, they demonstrate how to display results from nearbySearch() on a map.

However, I just want to retrieve and use the result array. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by still following the callback example but not using the `createMarker` bit in the code. The callback has a `result` argument that you can use any which way, i.e.:

```js
function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (const result of results) {
      //... print the result object for example
      console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    }
  }
}
```